# Syntax highlighting in Python prompt

Tags: interface, customization, command-line

The [Blender Python documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/info_quickstart.html) has a very attractive colour scheme:

[image: Example python prompt]

Is it possible to get this colour scheme in the Python prompt?

Comment: The text editor supports syntax highlighting, the py console is barely able to auto-indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax highlighting in the Python command line is not supported currently.